# Users Vs Members

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

This is more like a question for an advice rather than a precise answer...

In my CakePHP app, I will have backend users and frontend members. They have completely different roles and permissions (users are application managers, members are visitors that register on the website without any access to the application backend). Should I use different tables for these two authorization types, or should I just manage them with a role parameter and bind tables to their profiles depending on it, and why is one solution better than the other?

Comment: Usually you would call them members and and admins (not users). But yeah, use a single users table with two different roles for role_id - and sth like [Tiny](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/18/tinyauth-the-fastest-and-easiest-authorization-for-cake2/) and you got it covered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the same table and `role` or `type` field. You will have only one login and it will be easy to manage the accounts.

Use ACL or a custom permission system to allow them to different controllers/actions.

Answer (score 2):

For permissions, I have 3 ways to do it :

**The strict-role way :**
Every role of your application has access to functions with their prefix, but not any other prefix.

> Ex : **admin** has access to *admin_edit*, but not *customer_edit*

You add a role varchar or enum in your `users` table, the routing prefixes in `Config/core.php` and you allow the access in a `AppController::beforeFilter` : each role is allowed to access to his prefix only.

**The hierarchical way:**
Your application's roles are ordered in a hierarchical way, where a role has access to his prefix and every prefixes under him.

> Ex : **admin** has access to *admin_edit* and *customer_edit*, but
>   **customer** has not access to *admin_edit*

You add a role varchar or enum in your `users` table, the routing prefixes in `Config/core.php` and you allow the access in a `AppController::beforeFilter` by checking for each `$this->request->params['prefix']` which roles can has access to it.

**The custom way:**
You need your admin to access to some functions, but not all. You need another role to access some functions admin can access, and some functions admin cannot.

> Ex : **admin** can access to *admin_edit* and *customer_edit*, but not
>   *customer_create* or *user_stat*. **customer** can have access to
>   *customer_edit*, *customer_create* and *user_stat*, but not *admin_edit* or
>   *user_edit*

Use ACL. It's not the easiest way to manage permissions into your application, but if you want specific permissions, it's the best way. So remember this : *only use ACL if you really need it.*

Answer (score 0):

I agree with cornelb: one table only. Here are some additional reasons:

- If you add foreign key constraints, it might be messy to make them refer to both the app managers table, and the visitors table. Always when you want to point to a user, you'd need 2 fields, instead of 1 (a field pointing to the managers table, and one to the visitors table — and exactly one of them has to be null). And what if you need 2 user id fields in a row, with foreign keys? Then you'd suddenly need 4 fields. Simper with all keys pointing to just one table (and user type decided by the above-mentioned field).
- Sometimes you might want the user id be part of a primary key — but that's more complicated, if you have two different user id fields, one in each table. Because then the database cannot guarantee that each user id is unique — you'd have to do it yourself at the application level.